# drupal 8 conditional field

Tags: jquery, drupal, custom-lists, drupal-8

I want to add province and city fields to user entity in drupal 8. by changing province, list of cities should be updated. in drupal 7 I've done this with conditional field module, but this module isn't ready for drupal 8 yet.
what is the right way to do this in drupal 8?
should I add fields and then add jquery to my registration template for doing this or is there a better and standard way to do this.
thank you.

Comment: If anybody looking for now, here we have https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields  for drupal 8, which is also compatible with drupal 9 also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a little bit of (PHP) code, it's possible to use [Drupal's states processing](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/8.2.x) to explicitly say which fields should be shown or hidden given which conditions.

For example, this shows design type, design location, and design discipline fields when Design (term ID 4) is selected in the category field, etc:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 *
 * On Work node add and edit, set only selected category's associated
 * vocabularies as visible.
 */
function mass_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id != 'node_work_form' && $form_id != 'node_work_edit_form') {
    return;
  }
  if (isset($form['field_category'])) {
    $states_when_category_is_design = array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="field_category"]' => array('value' => '4'),
      ),
    );

    $states_when_category_is_advocacy = array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="field_category"]' => array('value' => '19'),
      ),
    );

    $states_when_category_is_research = array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="field_category"]' => array('value' => '25'),
      ),
    );

    if (isset($form['field_design_type'])) {
      $form['field_design_type']['#states'] = $states_when_category_is_design;
    }

    if (isset($form['field_design_location'])) {
      $form['field_design_location']['#states'] = $states_when_category_is_design;
    };

    if (isset($form['field_design_discipline'])) {
      $form['field_design_discipline']['#states'] = $states_when_category_is_design;
    };

    if (isset($form['field_advocacy_type'])) {
      $form['field_advocacy_type']['#states'] = $states_when_category_is_advocacy;
    };

    if (isset($form['field_research_type'])) {
      $form['field_research_type']['#states'] = $states_when_category_is_research;
    };
  }
}
```

(This code is shamelessly stolen from Mauricio Dinarte aka dinarcon, my colleague and fellow worker-owner at Agaric.)

Comment: Important update to this—nothing about the form state code, which is solid, but—if you want this to appear on both the node add (create content) form as well as the edit form, you need to act on two different form alter hooks in Drupal 8: node_NODETYPE_form and node_NODETYPE_edit_form.  (Answer's code updated to reflect this.)

Comment: mass_form_alter the "mass" is your admin theme?

Comment: @TikaL13 Good question! That would work, but we didn't want a custom admin theme so in this case we put the code in our install profile, which is called 'mass'.  It would also work in a custom module, but as your question makes clear, it would not work in your main theme if showing edit forms in the admin theme!

Comment: Sorry, Drupal noob, but I'm having the same concern and forced to use Drupal 8. I've found the given link several times, but to me it seems incomplete. Where does this code go? How does it get called? Is there an example of a complete module or where to start with this?

Comment: Hi @RyanH!  This can go in any custom module.  All that needs is a 'module_name' folder with a 'module_name.info' file (something like http://cgit.drupalcode.org/examples/tree/fapi_example/fapi_example.info.yml ) and a 'module_name.module' file with the above code following an opening <?php and where 'mass' is replaced with your 'module_name'.  For a great deal more info on modules, see https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules

Answer (score 0):

Drupal provides feature you need by the [Conditional fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module.

As  [early adopter](https://www.drupal.org/8/faq#1), you may consider to follow [this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2609628) and eventually support the Community with the porting to Drupal 8.

Today, I personally go with Drupal 8 only when all - or most of -  features I need are supported by stable contrib modules. Otherwise, I go with Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to display or hide fields with dependency in a dropdown select list.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_CONTENT_TYPE_form' || $form_id == 'node_CONTENT_TYPE_edit_form') {
    conditional_field_select(
      $form,
      'field_target',
      'field_controller',
      ['value_a', 'value_b', 'value_c'],
      'visible'
    );
  }
}

function conditional_field_select(array &$form, $targetField, $controlledBy, array $values, $state = 'invisible', $cond = 'or') {
  if (isset($form[$targetField]) && isset($form[$controlledBy])) {
    $form[$targetField]['#states'][$state] = [];
    foreach ($values as $value) {
      array_push($form[$targetField]['#states'][$state], ['select[name=' . $controlledBy . ']' => ['value' => $value]]);
      if (end($values) !== $value) {
        array_push($form[$targetField]['#states'][$state], $cond);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It can easily be changed to input.

```
array_push($form[$targetField]['#states'][$state], [':input[name=' . $controlledBy . ']' => ['value' => $value]]);
```